# AWS VPC EC2 Setting AD DNS Custom DNS for instance running in another VPC

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Here is my scenario: 1. I have two peered VPCs VPC1 which is running Active Directory integrated DNS Service with my domain as example.local.

There is another VPC2 which has both VPC DNS with enableDnsHostnames and enableDnsSupport options set to yes.

All the Security Groups rules associated with Active Directory Instance in VPC1 allow UDP and TCP port 53 traffic.

Configuration for /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf is as supersede domain-name-server a.b.c.d x.y.u.v where a.b.c.d and x.y.u.v are my AD domain controllers.

Configuration for /etc/hosts file is

a.b.c.d DC1.example.local

Configuration for /etc/network/interfaces

```
                1. dns-nameservers a.b.c.d
                2. dns-search example.local
```

VPC Peering connection has Requester VPC (vpc-xxxxxxx) peering connection attributes: DNS resolution from accepter VPC to private IP Enabled Accepter VPC (vpc-yyyyyyy) peering connection attributes: DNS resolution from requester VPC to private IP Enabled
Its Ubuntu EC2 instance and I have rebooted the instance after making configuration changes.

After Reboot the contents of /etc/resolv.conf file are

nameserver 10.x.y.z
search us-west-2.compute.internal
Which is Amazon provided internal VPC DNS for VPC2.

Please explain what I am missing here...Why my EC2 instance is not pointing to Active Directory DNS which is running in VPC1? I can set the DNSOptions set for the VPC2 to resolve to AD provided DNS. But I dont want that to be the case for all the instances in VPC2. What are my options to configure only specific instances to the AD DNS in VPC1 without changing the DNSOption Set??